# When to use double quotes in yaml

Tags: yaml

I notice that in `yaml`, I can at time use double quotes. What are the rules for using double quotes?

```
- name: MOCK_EMAIL
  value: false
- name: START_MODE
  value: prod
- name: DB_CASSANDRA_PORT
  value: "9042" <-- this is in "" but rest of the entries are not
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By quoting the port number, you'll get a string. If you just use `9042` (without quotes) you define the value as a number. It depends on the application if this really makes a difference.